# Autolayout vs frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

Let's say that i have a view loaded from a nib that has layout constraints changing its appearance depending on its size.

I load the view from the nib and get a reference to UIView.
I then manually change view's frame (e.g make it really big or small) and add it as a subview to already visible view.

Will the constraint system automatically figure that frame change should trigger auto layout recompilation? How does auto layout mix with manual frame/bounds changes? Where can i get detailed documentation on this?

Comment: The Auto Layout Guide may be of assistance. found at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, if your want the autolayout to re-apply you need to call `[view layoutIfNeeded]`, and if you set frames before the layout finished to apply, it will be override. My advice is to modify constraints instead of setting frames.

Comment: So the constraint system is incompatible with manual frame settings? Where can i get docs on this?

Comment: It can coexist but you have to be careful, see the documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH15-SW1