# Swift: How many types of method available for alignment UILabel and other widget in swift?

Tags: swift, alignment, text-alignment

Hello i am flutter developer and new to swift.
could you please help me to figure out which method is perfect or in which situation which method should I user for alignment widgets in swift?

> Like : UILabel, Image,Padding , Row,COlumn , have two tips of method see below.

```
//Method - 1
scoreLabel.frame = CGRect( x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50)
//method - 2 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([scoreLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
                                     scoreLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),])
```

> So now is other any other method also for alignment or which would be used in live project or right way for every devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are different approaches in laying out UI elements in [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit). The first one is manually setting frames for your views, the other one is called [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html). There're [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654286/advantages-of-setting-constraints-vs-setting-frames-of-uiviews) [of discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850196/auto-layout-vs-frame-sizes) [comparing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826732/cgrect-vs-constraints-in-programmatic-gui-design) [their differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741841/autolayout-vs-frames).

Apart from UIKit, there's also another way of building UI for Apple platforms, which becoming more popular – [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/).

Comment: it means there are mainly 2 methods 1) manual and 2) auto-layout right?

Comment: For UIKit, yes.

Comment: do you have any example blogs for this both? where can I under it in a more straightforward way without riding more documents?

Comment: There're plenty, just search for them. Here's one: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/8/2/building-a-uikit-user-interface-programmatically And some another one: https://fluffy.es/frame-vs-autolayout/